# How should I get a specific part of the URI

Tags: c#, request, uri

If I have the URI "http://www.test.com/something" and I want the "www.test.com" part.
What should I use? (what is the best for this)

- [Request.Url.DnsSafeHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.dnssafehost.aspx)
- [Request.Url.Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx)
- [Request.Url.Authority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx)

I asked this question in the [CHAT](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4668456#4668456), but didn't get so much luck.

Comment: I'm not sure this matters, but what do you want to use the extracted host for?

Comment: Show to the user =/ ( I know, but it was a request, what can we do when the client wants something?! )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick with `Request.Url.Authority`, so if your host has another port than `80`, it will be displayed (if this important for you).

---

**Example:**

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.test.com:8888/something");
Console.WriteLine(myUri.Authority);
Console.WriteLine(myUri.Host);
```

---

**Output:**

> www.test.com:8888
>   www.test.com

---

If you just want to display the host part to the user, no need to bother with `DnsSafeHost` anyway. You would use it if you need to convert a IPv6 address e.g. `http://[fe80::200:39ff:fe36:1a2d%4]/temp/example.htm` to `fe80::200:39ff:fe36:1a2d%4` for name resolution.

Comment: I'm taking your answer as the right one because of the explanation on DnsSafeHost and the great layout on your answer (easy to read/understand) But [@Deanna](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11652013/662581) and [+Nikola](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11652020/662581) are great answers too

Answer (score 4):

As comment stated, it may be important for which purpose you intend to use hostname.

Generally, I would use
[Uri.Authority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx), or combine components I need.

Authority provides two key components to locate a service: 1) hostname 2) port.
Other two properties only give you hostname.

For example, if I was accessing website which is not hosted on default port, but for example 81 (http://example.com:81), I'd like to be informed about port number too.